# On and off buttons not working properly

Tags: android, button

I coded an Android app, in which it has two buttons, one for mute the `music_player` and other for unmute it. But when I press the mute button two times in order to increase the media volume I need to press unmute button two times. How to avoid this? I want to unmute the media volume no matter how many times I mute the media volume. I used the following code:

**Mute:**

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

**Unmute:**

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
```

*Editor's note: The two code segments above are identical. That's probably incorrect.*

Comment: Implement toggle button to your mute/unmute stream

Comment: any example of how to do it?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-togglebutton-example/

Comment: is it ok that you create two different constructors? I think there should be only one, right? Just one, lets say private AudioManager am, then you can use setStreamMute with different options I think.. btw but first you must of course initialize this AudioManager.

Comment: actually these two lines are inside the  on clicklistener of button

Comment: try declare in global field this `private AudioManager am`, inside `onCreate` init by `am = (AudioManager)...` and inside unmute button paste just `am.set...true` and inside mute button `am.set...false`. Maybe there is also any misunderstood so try paste more code, thanks.

Comment: what's the status of problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may specify a `boolean` flag `isMute` and use it to toggle mute by one button just like this:

```
boolean isMute = false;
Button mMuteButton;

...

mMuteButton.setOnclickListener(
   new OnClickListener {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         AudioManager am = (AudioManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
         am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, !isMute);
         isMute = !isMute;
      }
   });
```

Or if you extremely want to use two buttons, so just disable one after mute or unmute